# Difference between Kivy camera and opencv camera

Tags: python, opencv, camera, kivy, motion-detection

What is the difference between Kivy Camera and opencv ? I am asking this because in Kivy Camera the image gets adjusted according to frame size but in opencv this does not happen. Also I am not able to do motion detection in kivy camera whereas I found a great tutorial for motion detection on opencv. If someone can clarify the difference it would be appreciated ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

opencv is a computer vision framework (hence the c-v) which can interact with device cameras. Kivy is a cross-platform development tool which can interact with device cameras.  It makes sense that there are good motion detection tutorials for opencv but not kivy camera, since this isnt really what kivy is for.

Comment: Oh I must clarify the question. I meant why is it so easy to do motion detection in opencv relative to Kivy camera. Is the image informatuion stored in a different manner ? I know opencv can display the information as a numpy array but I have no idea how kivy camera stores the information. Sorry for any confusion